# Create input of type button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a wcf service that get values from database and return json object. I'm trying to create input buttons depend on returned values as :

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "My Servic URL",
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    var foo = document.getElementById("hmengcont");
    foo.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < eval(response.d).length; i++) {
      var element = document.createElement("input");
      //Assign different attributes to the element.
      element.type = "button";
      element.id = eval(response.d)[i].CityID;
      element.class = "show-page-loading-msg";
      element.style = "width: 100%;height: 50px; border-radius: 5px;-webkit-appearance: inherit;cursor: pointer; opacity: 5.1;z-index: 2;color: #131212;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);";
      element.value = eval(response.d)[i].CityNameEng; // Really? You want the default value to be the type string?
      element.name = eval(response.d)[i].CityID;
      element.onclick = function() { // Note this is a function
        alert(element.value);
      }
      ");";
      foo.appendChild(element);
    }
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    alert(a.responseText);
  }
});
```

the buttons created successfully and all of them has his own correct values , but on click the alert return only the latest value.

Comment: 1) use the `this` keyword in the click handler to reference the clicked button: `console.log(this.value)`. 2) you should use jQuery to create the element - you can shorten the code in the `for` loop to just a few lines 3) use CSS classes on your element instead of inline styling 4) *don't use eval* - it's terrible practice, made even worse when you use it multiple times to decode the same object. 5) use a single delegated event handler to handle clicks on all the buttons you're adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your alert instead of  `element.value` change it as `this.value`. Something like below,

```
element.onclick = function() { // Note this is a function
   alert(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "My Servic URL",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var foo = document.getElementById("hmengcont");
        foo.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < eval(response.d).length; i++)
        {
            $("<input>", {
                type: "button",
                id: eval(response.d)[i].CityID,
                class: "show-page-loading-msg",
                style: "width: 100%;height: 50px; border-radius: 5px;-webkit-appearance: inherit;cursor: pointer; opacity: 5.1;z-index: 2;color: #131212;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);",
                value: eval(response.d)[i].CityNameEng, // Really? You want the default value to be the type string?
                name: eval(response.d)[i].CityID
            }).appendTo($("#hmengcont"));
        }
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        alert(a.responseText);
    }
});
$(document).on("click", "button.show-page-loading-msg", function () {
    var arrButtons = $("button.show-page-loading-msg");
    $.each(arrButtons, function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```